# Convert and concatenate data from two columns of a csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file which contains data in two columns, as follows:

1. 40500    38921
2. 43782    32768
3. 55136    49651
4. 63451    60669
5. 50550    36700
6. 61651    34321

and so on...

I want to convert each data into it's hex equivalent, then concatenate them, and write them into a column in another csv file.

For example: hex(40500) = 9E34, and hex(38921) = 9809.
So, in output csv file, element A1 would be 9E349809

So, i am expecting column A in output csv file to be:

1. 9E349809
2. AB068000
3. D760C1F3
4. F7DBECFD
5. C5768F5C
6. F0D38611

I referred a sample code which concatenates two columns, but am struggling with the converting them to hex and then concatenating them. Following is the code:-

```
import csv

inputFile = 'input.csv'
outputFile = 'output.csv'

with open(inputFile) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open(outputFile, 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = [''.join([row[0], row[1]])] + row[2:]
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

How can i convert data in each column to its hex equivalent, then concatenate them and write them in another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in 4 steps:

1. **Read the lines** from the input `csv` file
2. Use formatting options to **get the hex values** of each number
3. Perform **string concatenation** to get your result
4. **Write to new csv** file.

**Sample Code:**

```
with open (outputFile, 'w') as outfile:
    with open (inputFile,'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:             # Iterate through each line
            left, right = int(line.split()[0]), int(line.split()[1]) # split left and right blocks
            newstr = '{:x}'.format(left)+'{:x}'.format(right) # create new string using hex values excluding '0x'
            outfile.write(newstr)   # write to output file
    print ('Conversion completed')
print ('Closing outputfile')
```

**Sample Output:**

```
In[44] line = '40500 38921'
Out[50]: '9e349809'
```

Comment: Tried this, but i get the following error:- ***left, right = int(line.split()[0]), int(line.split()[0]) # split left and right blocks
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '40500,38921'***

Comment: I'm sorry, I might have used `[0]` for both variables, fixed that. For the value error.. is it for any particular line in your csv or you're trying it on console first? It worked for me on console.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

ParvBanks solution is good (clear and functionnal), I would simplify it a little like that:

```
with open (inputFile,'r') as infile, open (outputFile, 'w+') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write("".join(["{:x}".format(int(v)) for v in line.split()]))
```

Comment: Nice one! The simplification within the loop is great! However, I prefer to open the files separately, just in case there are more than one input files writing to a common output file.